# Is AC invoked in the claim "the product/sum of a sequence of separable metrizable spaces is separable"?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, descriptive-set-theory

**The Claim**:The product/sum of a sequence of separable metrizable spaces is separable.

Here the sum of a family $((X_i, d_i))_{i\in I}$ of metric spaces is defined (up to isometry) as follows: By copying the metric of each $X_i$ on a set of the same cardinality, we can assume that the sets $X_i$ are pairwise disjoint. Let $X=\cup_{i\in I}X_i$. We define a metric $d$ on $X$ by letting $d(x, y)=d_i(x, y)$ if $x, y\in X_i$, and $d(x, y)=1$ if otherwise. The topology of this metric space is the sum of the topologies of $((X_i, d_i))$.

**Source**: *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Alexander Kechris.

**My Question**: I am almost certain that the claim involves the lemma "countable union of countable sets is countable": Let $D_i\subseteq X_i$ be the countable dense set in each $X_i$, and let $D=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}D_i$. Then $D$ is a countable dense set of $X$. Thus, the *Axiom of Choice* is at play here. Is my suspicion justified, or is there a way to prove the claim without invoking AC? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need countable choice since the proof require "choosing" a separable set for each of the metric spaces and this choice may not be canonical in any way. Countable choice is stronger and implies that the countable union of countable sets is countable. Also I think you should add the proof to your question since not everyone has the book you mentioned.

Comment: @Math_Images_Only Yeah I don't see any other way to prove the claim without constructing a countable dense set for $X$ using the countable dense set in each $X_i$. Well, thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: The sum of metric spaces as defined here need not define a metric. If $x,y\in X_i$ satisfy $d_i(x,y)>2$ and $z\in X_j$ with $j\neq i$, then $d(x,y)>2=1+1=d(x,z)+d(z,y)$, violating the triangle inequality.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker You are absolutely right! Geez I distrust this book even more now...

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, Kechris mentions on the same page as this excerpt that every metric is topologically equivalent to one where $d(x,y) < 1$, since we can replace $d$ by $d' = \frac{d}{1+d}$. This ensures the triangle inequality holds.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, the direct sum of metrizable topological spaces is metrizable.

Comment: In my experience Kechris's book is very reliable. Why do you say you distrust it? There is no claim made that all the results go through in ZF!

Comment: @AlexKruckman It has more to do with what my advisor told me. He said that there will only be a few cases where AOC is innocently invoked throughout the book, and then I found out that AOC is invoked left and right in just the first few pages, which subconsciously affected my impression of the text. Then Michael’s counter example further strengthened that bias. It’s a case of transference I presume.

Comment: Indeed, you'll find that some choice is absolutely crucial to even the very basics of topology in $\mathbb{R}$ or general metric spaces. For most things, full choice is not necessary - you can usually get away with dependent choice (which is a bit stronger than countable choice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sum case, it is at least as strong as the claim that a countable union of countable sets is countable. If we have a choice of a countable dense set for each of the spaces, the problem is equivalent to the claim that the countable union of countable sets is countable.

For consider a countable family of countable sets $(X_i)_{i \in D}$, and suppose WLOG the $X_i$ are pairwise disjoint. Equip each $X_i$ with the discrete metric. Then $T = \bigcup\limits_{i \in D} X_i$ also has the discrete metric, so the only dense set in $T$ is $T$ itself. Thus, $T$ is separable if and only if it is countable.

Some amount of choice is needed to show the countable union of countable sets is countable. This is strictly weaker than countable choice.

Comment: Yes, but you need countable choice to pick a countable dense set from each space to begin with.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Good point. I’ve edited the answer accordingly.